Doughnut chart with only top corners rounded
I have been trying for a few hours to accomplish the following Chart with D3.js:

It's easy to accomplish a similar result following the default examples, and getting something like this:

The problem is when I try to just round the corners on top of each segment (like first screenshot) because the default cornerRadius method will apply it radius to all the corners.
I tried a few approaches suggested by using the amazing D3.js Assistant (Chat GPT) but none of them helped me to do it because it's failing on calculating the correct values for the Arcs, and I'm super noob when talking about manual making an SVG (even after reading the docs).
Some approaches I tried:

Remove existing rounded corners by using a custom method to create the d path.
Creating each segment "by hand" with a custom method
Round all corners, and render a second "layer" of segments without rounding and shorter so it fakes bottom corners to not have roundings (this can work, but feels hacky)
Hitting my head on the keyboard

Useful links I found:

Vanilla SVG rounded corners (12 years old thread): Answers helped me a lot to understand Arcs and how they work, I can sucessfuly write by hand an Arc, but, problem with the existing values coming from D3.


Based on the images, I'm treating the top corners to be the outer corners, my solution could be adopted to other combinations of corners.
The easiest way to achieve your effect is to modify the d3-arc source directly and roll your own D3 module.
All you need to do to create the functionality is remove a few lines:
  // Does the sector’s inner ring (or point) have rounded corners?
  else if (rc0 > epsilon) {
    t0 = cornerTangents(x10, y10, x11, y11, r0, -rc0, cw);
    t1 = cornerTangents(x01, y01, x00, y00, r0, -rc0, cw);

    context.lineTo(t0.cx + t0.x01, t0.cy + t0.y01);

    // Have the corners merged?
    if (rc0 < rc) context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc0, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);

    // Otherwise, draw the two corners and the ring.
    else {
      context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc0, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t0.y11, t0.x11), !cw);
      context.arc(0, 0, r0, atan2(t0.cy + t0.y11, t0.cx + t0.x11), atan2(t1.cy + t1.y11, t1.cx + t1.x11), cw);
      context.arc(t1.cx, t1.cy, rc0, atan2(t1.y11, t1.x11), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);
    }

This handles the inner rounded corners. By removing this only the code for rounding the outer corners remains. The result should be something like this:

I've created a quick and dirty example without compiling this properly by dropping the source code into a previously created module (for chevron arcs) and avoided many dependencies. In other words, this isn't the best version to use, but it shows the change easily enough and can let you test the effect. This example is below.
This new arc function can be accessed via d3.customArc() as opposed to d3.arc() and can be treated as d3.arc() - the only difference is it won't apply a cornerRadius to the inside corners.


let data = [
    {name: "A", value: 100 },
    {name: "B", value: 200 },
    {name: "C", value: 300 },
    {name: "D", value: 400 },
  ]
  
  const width = 400;
  const radius = 150;
  const height = 400;

  const arc = d3.customArc()
      .innerRadius(radius * 0.67)
      .outerRadius(radius - 1)
      .cornerRadius(20);

  const pie = d3.pie()
      .padAngle(1 / radius)
      .sort(null)
      .value(d => d.value);

  const color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(data.map(d => d.name))
      .range(d3.quantize(t => d3.interpolateSpectral(t * 0.8 + 0.1), data.length).reverse());

  const svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;");
      


  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll()
    .data(pie(data))
    .join("path")
      .attr("fill", d => color(d.data.name))
      .attr("d", arc)
    .append("title")
      .text(d => `${d.data.name}: ${d.data.value.toLocaleString()}`);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 12)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .selectAll()
    .data(pie(data))
    .join("text")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${arc.centroid(d)})`)
      .call(text => text.append("tspan")
          .attr("y", "-0.4em")
          .attr("font-weight", "bold")
          .text(d => d.data.name))
      .call(text => text.filter(d => (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) > 0.25).append("tspan")
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("y", "0.7em")
          .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
          .text(d => d.data.value.toLocaleString("en-US")));
<svg width="960" height="960"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="d3customArc.js"></script>

<script>

(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports, require('d3-path')) :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports', 'd3-path'], factory) :
  (factory((global.d3 = global.d3 || {}),global.d3));
}(this, (function (exports,d3Path) { 'use strict';


var constant = function(x) {
  return function constant() {
    return x;
  };
};

var epsilon = 1e-12;
var pi = Math.PI;
var halfPi = pi / 2;
var tau = 2 * pi;

var atan2 = Math.atan2;
var asin = Math.asin;
var cos = Math.cos;
var sin = Math.sin;
var acos = Math.acos;
var atan = Math.atan;
var abs = Math.abs;
var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
var min = Math.min;
var max = Math.max;

function withPath(shape) {
  let digits = 3;

  shape.digits = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return digits;
    if (_ == null) {
      digits = null;
    } else {
      const d = floor(_);
      if (!(d >= 0)) throw new RangeError(`invalid digits: ${_}`);
      digits = d;
    }
    return shape;
  };

  return () => new d3.path(digits);
}


function arcInnerRadius(d) {
  return d.innerRadius;
}

function arcOuterRadius(d) {
  return d.outerRadius;
}

function arcStartAngle(d) {
  return d.startAngle;
}

function arcEndAngle(d) {
  return d.endAngle;
}

function arcPadAngle(d) {
  return d && d.padAngle; // Note: optional!
}

function intersect(x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
  var x10 = x1 - x0, y10 = y1 - y0,
      x32 = x3 - x2, y32 = y3 - y2,
      t = y32 * x10 - x32 * y10;
  if (t * t < epsilon) return;
  t = (x32 * (y0 - y2) - y32 * (x0 - x2)) / t;
  return [x0 + t * x10, y0 + t * y10];
}

// Compute perpendicular offset line of length rc.
// http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html
function cornerTangents(x0, y0, x1, y1, r1, rc, cw) {
  var x01 = x0 - x1,
      y01 = y0 - y1,
      lo = (cw ? rc : -rc) / sqrt(x01 * x01 + y01 * y01),
      ox = lo * y01,
      oy = -lo * x01,
      x11 = x0 + ox,
      y11 = y0 + oy,
      x10 = x1 + ox,
      y10 = y1 + oy,
      x00 = (x11 + x10) / 2,
      y00 = (y11 + y10) / 2,
      dx = x10 - x11,
      dy = y10 - y11,
      d2 = dx * dx + dy * dy,
      r = r1 - rc,
      D = x11 * y10 - x10 * y11,
      d = (dy < 0 ? -1 : 1) * sqrt(max(0, r * r * d2 - D * D)),
      cx0 = (D * dy - dx * d) / d2,
      cy0 = (-D * dx - dy * d) / d2,
      cx1 = (D * dy + dx * d) / d2,
      cy1 = (-D * dx + dy * d) / d2,
      dx0 = cx0 - x00,
      dy0 = cy0 - y00,
      dx1 = cx1 - x00,
      dy1 = cy1 - y00;

  // Pick the closer of the two intersection points.
  // TODO Is there a faster way to determine which intersection to use?
  if (dx0 * dx0 + dy0 * dy0 > dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1) cx0 = cx1, cy0 = cy1;

  return {
    cx: cx0,
    cy: cy0,
    x01: -ox,
    y01: -oy,
    x11: cx0 * (r1 / r - 1),
    y11: cy0 * (r1 / r - 1)
  };
}

var customArc = function() {
  var innerRadius = arcInnerRadius,
      outerRadius = arcOuterRadius,
      cornerRadius = constant(0),
      padRadius = null,
      startAngle = arcStartAngle,
      endAngle = arcEndAngle,
      padAngle = arcPadAngle,
      context = null,
      path = withPath(customArc);

  function customArc() {
    var buffer,
        r,
        r0 = +innerRadius.apply(this, arguments),
        r1 = +outerRadius.apply(this, arguments),
        a0 = startAngle.apply(this, arguments) - halfPi,
        a1 = endAngle.apply(this, arguments) - halfPi,
        da = abs(a1 - a0),
        cw = a1 > a0;

    if (!context) context = buffer = path();

    // Ensure that the outer radius is always larger than the inner radius.
    if (r1 < r0) r = r1, r1 = r0, r0 = r;

    // Is it a point?
    if (!(r1 > epsilon)) context.moveTo(0, 0);

    // Or is it a circle or annulus?
    else if (da > tau - epsilon) {
      context.moveTo(r1 * cos(a0), r1 * sin(a0));
      context.arc(0, 0, r1, a0, a1, !cw);
      if (r0 > epsilon) {
        context.moveTo(r0 * cos(a1), r0 * sin(a1));
        context.arc(0, 0, r0, a1, a0, cw);
      }
    }

    // Or is it a circular or annular sector?
    else {
      var a01 = a0,
          a11 = a1,
          a00 = a0,
          a10 = a1,
          da0 = da,
          da1 = da,
          ap = padAngle.apply(this, arguments) / 2,
          rp = (ap > epsilon) && (padRadius ? +padRadius.apply(this, arguments) : sqrt(r0 * r0 + r1 * r1)),
          rc = min(abs(r1 - r0) / 2, +cornerRadius.apply(this, arguments)),
          rc0 = rc,
          rc1 = rc,
          t0,
          t1;

      // Apply padding? Note that since r1 ≥ r0, da1 ≥ da0.
      if (rp > epsilon) {
        var p0 = asin(rp / r0 * sin(ap)),
            p1 = asin(rp / r1 * sin(ap));
        if ((da0 -= p0 * 2) > epsilon) p0 *= (cw ? 1 : -1), a00 += p0, a10 -= p0;
        else da0 = 0, a00 = a10 = (a0 + a1) / 2;
        if ((da1 -= p1 * 2) > epsilon) p1 *= (cw ? 1 : -1), a01 += p1, a11 -= p1;
        else da1 = 0, a01 = a11 = (a0 + a1) / 2;
      }

      var x01 = r1 * cos(a01),
          y01 = r1 * sin(a01),
          x10 = r0 * cos(a10),
          y10 = r0 * sin(a10);

      // Apply rounded corners?
      if (rc > epsilon) {
        var x11 = r1 * cos(a11),
            y11 = r1 * sin(a11),
            x00 = r0 * cos(a00),
            y00 = r0 * sin(a00),
            oc;

        // Restrict the corner radius according to the sector angle. If this
        // intersection fails, it’s probably because the arc is too small, so
        // disable the corner radius entirely.
        if (da < pi) {
          if (oc = intersect(x01, y01, x00, y00, x11, y11, x10, y10)) {
            var ax = x01 - oc[0],
                ay = y01 - oc[1],
                bx = x11 - oc[0],
                by = y11 - oc[1],
                kc = 1 / sin(acos((ax * bx + ay * by) / (sqrt(ax * ax + ay * ay) * sqrt(bx * bx + by * by))) / 2),
                lc = sqrt(oc[0] * oc[0] + oc[1] * oc[1]);
            rc0 = min(rc, (r0 - lc) / (kc - 1));
            rc1 = min(rc, (r1 - lc) / (kc + 1));
          } else {
            rc0 = rc1 = 0;
          }
        }
      }

      // Is the sector collapsed to a line?
      if (!(da1 > epsilon)) context.moveTo(x01, y01);

      // Does the sector’s outer ring have rounded corners?
      else if (rc1 > epsilon) {
        t0 = cornerTangents(x00, y00, x01, y01, r1, rc1, cw);
        t1 = cornerTangents(x11, y11, x10, y10, r1, rc1, cw);

        context.moveTo(t0.cx + t0.x01, t0.cy + t0.y01);

        // Have the corners merged?
        if (rc1 < rc) context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc1, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);

        // Otherwise, draw the two corners and the ring.
        else {
          context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc1, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t0.y11, t0.x11), !cw);
          context.arc(0, 0, r1, atan2(t0.cy + t0.y11, t0.cx + t0.x11), atan2(t1.cy + t1.y11, t1.cx + t1.x11), !cw);
          context.arc(t1.cx, t1.cy, rc1, atan2(t1.y11, t1.x11), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);
        }
      }

      // Or is the outer ring just a circular arc?
      else context.moveTo(x01, y01), context.arc(0, 0, r1, a01, a11, !cw);

      // Is there no inner ring, and it’s a circular sector?
      // Or perhaps it’s an annular sector collapsed due to padding?
      if (!(r0 > epsilon) || !(da0 > epsilon)) context.lineTo(x10, y10);

      // Does the sector’s inner ring (or point) have rounded corners?
      /* // Start Changes: Remove:
      else if (rc0 > epsilon) {
        t0 = cornerTangents(x10, y10, x11, y11, r0, -rc0, cw);
        t1 = cornerTangents(x01, y01, x00, y00, r0, -rc0, cw);

        context.lineTo(t0.cx + t0.x01, t0.cy + t0.y01);

        // Have the corners merged?
        if (rc0 < rc) context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc0, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);

        // Otherwise, draw the two corners and the ring.
        else {
          context.arc(t0.cx, t0.cy, rc0, atan2(t0.y01, t0.x01), atan2(t0.y11, t0.x11), !cw);
          context.arc(0, 0, r0, atan2(t0.cy + t0.y11, t0.cx + t0.x11), atan2(t1.cy + t1.y11, t1.cx + t1.x11), cw);
          context.arc(t1.cx, t1.cy, rc0, atan2(t1.y11, t1.x11), atan2(t1.y01, t1.x01), !cw);
        }
      }
      */ // End Changes : Remove
      // Or is the inner ring just a circular arc?
      else context.arc(0, 0, r0, a10, a00, cw);
    }

    context.closePath();

    if (buffer) return context = null, buffer + "" || null;
  }

  customArc.centroid = function() {
    var r = (+innerRadius.apply(this, arguments) + +outerRadius.apply(this, arguments)) / 2,
        a = (+startAngle.apply(this, arguments) + +endAngle.apply(this, arguments)) / 2 - pi / 2;
    return [cos(a) * r, sin(a) * r];
  };

  customArc.innerRadius = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (innerRadius = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : innerRadius;
  };

  customArc.outerRadius = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (outerRadius = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : outerRadius;
  };

  customArc.cornerRadius = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (cornerRadius = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) :cornerRadius;
  };
 

  customArc.padRadius = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (padRadius = _ == null ? null : typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : padRadius;
  };

  customArc.startAngle = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (startAngle = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : startAngle;
  };

  customArc.endAngle = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (endAngle = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : endAngle;
  };

  customArc.padAngle = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (padAngle = typeof _ === "function" ? _ : constant(+_), customArc) : padAngle;
  };

  customArc.context = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? ((context = _ == null ? null : _), customArc) : context;
  };

  return customArc;
}

exports.customArc = customArc;

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

})));

</script>



The source for d3-arc, which is entirely captured in this answer can be found here.

thanks! I didn't thought about extending existing methods, I ended up forking the repo and publishing my own version with toggable corners
